# Lizmap installation (Debian/Apache) : web configuration section

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, apache, lizmap

I work on a Debian 11 virtual server, apache and qgis server are installed and working.
I also installed the "qgis-lizmap-server-plugin" plugin and the "qgis plugin manager". I 'm trying now to install lizmap web client thanks to the official doc. [https://docs.lizmap.com/3.6/fr/install/linux.html](https://docs.lizmap.com/3.6/en/install/linux.html)
I have a question regarding the Web Configuration section.
I installed the necessary packages: curl, openssl, libssl1.1, nginx-full, nginx nginx-common, php7.4-fpm php7.4-cli php7.4-bz2 php7.4-curl php7.4-gd php7.4-intl php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring php7.4-pgsql php7.4-sqlite3 php7.4-xml php7.4-ldap php7.4-redis.

As requested by the doc, I created a lizmap.conf file under /etc/apache2/sites-available/ I replaced in this file the value localhost by the name of the server XXX.XXXX.fr
This is the only modification made in this file.
It is written in the doc:

> "You should declare the lizmap.local domain name somewhere (in your
> /etc/hosts, or into your DNS..), or replace it by your own domain
> name."

I did not declare a lizmap.local domain under /etc/hosts. Is it mandatory? Or is it optional? Because i have already done a similar action for qgis server installation.
Can someone explain this step? Are there any examples showing how to do this?

I tried anyway to activate the virtual host :

```
"ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/lizmap.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/lizmap.conf"
```

But when I try to restart apache, I can't. With these error messages:

```
root@XXXXXXXXXXXX:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-04-24 15:21:31 CEST; 1min 32s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 657246 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 30ms

avril 24 15:21:31 XXXXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
avril 24 15:21:31 XXXXXXXXXXXX apachectl[657249]: apache2: Syntax error on line 240 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 24 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/lizmap.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/fastc>
avril 24 15:21:31 XXXXXXXXXXXX apachectl[657246]: Action 'start' failed.
avril 24 15:21:31 XXXXXXXXXXXX apachectl[657246]: The Apache error log may have more information.
avril 24 15:21:31 XXXXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
avril 24 15:21:31 XXXXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
avril 24 15:21:31 XXXXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
 ESCOC
yntax error on line 24 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/lizmap.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/fastcgi_params;: No such file or directory
```

The error message seems to refer to line 24 of the lizmap.conf file. This line is:

```
include fastcgi_params;
```

Comment: Just to add related link if someone have the same issue and find this question, this question has been asked on the Lizmap mailing list as well : https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/lizmap/2023-April/000626.html

Answer (score 0):

Following to my previous post, For information, I limited myself to read the page https://docs.lizmap.com/3.6/fr/install/linux.html
I did not look at the pages https://docs.lizmap.com/3.6/fr/install/configuration.html and https://docs.lizmap.com/3.6/fr/install/advanced_install.html
I confirm that the URL [http://XXXX.XXXX.fr/cgi-bin/qgis_mapser…](http://XXXX.XXXX.fr/cgi-bin/qgis_mapser%E2%80%A6) MAP=
does NOT return any error.
I therefore did not define a host for lizmap since I had already done one for qgis server.
I created folders for the data.
I created a postgis database on a posgresql server hosted on another server. I have created the profiles.ini.php files
I edited the file like this:

```
[jdb:jauth]
driver=pgsql
host=IP of the server
port=5432
database="XXXXXX"
user=XXXXX
password=XXXXXX
search_path=public
sslmode=disable

[jdb:lizlog]
driver=pgsql
host=IP of the server
port=5432
database="XXXXXX"
user=XXXXXX
password=XXXXXX
search_path=public
sslmode=disable
```

I have successfully installed the lizmap web client sources.

the url

> http://XXXXXXXXX/lizmap/index.php/view/app/metadata

returns me Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) Server at XXXX.XXXX.fr Port 80

the URL

> http://XXXX.XXXX.fr/lizmap/

returns

```
<?php
/**
* @lizmap package
* @subpackage lizmap
* @author 3liz
* @copyright 2011 3liz
* @link http://3liz.com
* @license Mozilla Public License: http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/
*/
require('../application.init.php');
require (JELIX_LIB_CORE_PATH.'request/jClassicRequest.class.php');
checkAppOpened();
// Load the configuration
jApp::loadConfig('index/config.ini.php');
// new coordinator, which we indicate to jApp
jApp::setCoord(new jCoordinator());
// New request object, which we pass to the coordinator, to process the routing.
jApp::coord()->process(new jClassicRequest());
```

Weird... it returns the PHP code and it must be missing the end of the code (it starts with )
maybe there is a config to do in Apache to tell it to run the PHP code instead of returning it in text format...?
In the lizmapCOnfig.ini.php file, I only replaced the default IP 127.0.0.1 with the name of our server at the line wmsServerURL="http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserver.fcgi"

When I ran php configurator.php I got no error message.
When I ran php installer.php:

```
Installation is starting
All modules dependencies are ok
Installation starts
Module jelix installed
[error] An error occured during the installation of the module jcommunity: error during the connection XXXXIP of the server host postgresql

Installation is finished
```

I have successfully installed the demo. But these URLs return me a Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) Server at XXXXX.XXXX.fr Port 80:

http://xxxxx/lizmap/index.php/lizmap/service/?repository=montpellier&project=montpellier&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

http://xxxxxx/lizmap/index.php/lizmap/service/?repository=montpellier&project=montpellier&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Answer (score 0):

It's it works now. I had to set mod_php. And there was indeed a typo in my BDD postgresql settings.